# How to check why QRCodeReaderView cannot be imported on Android Studio?

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to have an activity which has QR code scanning view + spinner and button, like this:
[image]

First I decided to implement this as a standalone test app using [QRCodeReaderView](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView). It worked. Point the camera to a QR code, then a toast displaying its content will appear. The next step is to copy the codes to the actual project I'm working on.

I edited **build.gradle** and added this line:

```
 'implementation "com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3'
```

Then Android Studio pointed me to this:

> Class referenced in the layout file,
> `com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView`, was not found in
> the project or the libraries

Normally, Android Studio's auto import will automatically find it. But not this time. Also tried rebuilding the project, and invalidate caches / restart and re-syncing the project again. Doesn't work, either.

I'm on Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3 (the latest stable), and both projects pretty much use the same configuration, e.g:

- compileSdk 31
- minSdk 23
- targetSdk 31
- kotlin 1.6.0
- jvmTarget 1.8

No idea why QRCodeReaderView could be imported easily on the test app, but not on this main project. I have no idea how to debug this.

Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since the example worked, you know that your program has a bug (that's progress since you now know that it is possible for the program to work.)

I suggest a binary search. Add about half of your changes to the example. If the example still works then you know that those changes are ok. If not, then undo half of the changes you just made to see if that fixes the problem

Continue this process until you find the section of your code that causes the example to stop working.

This debugging technique is slow but will always find the problem.